# How to pass or retrieve linked list from one method to another method?

Tags: java, linked-list

First i want to retrieve patient linked list from `AddPatient()` method and show it on `ListPatient()` Method.

I try to retrieve by changing `public static void ListPatient()`; method to `public static void ListPatient(ListInterface<PatientDetails> patient)` but it doesn't work

```
package dsa;
import dsa.LList;
import dsa.ListInterface;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmergencyClinic {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        MainMenu();

    }

    public static void MainMenu(){

        int n = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Emergency Clinic!");
        System.out.println("1. Add Patient");
        System.out.println("2. Serve Patient");
        System.out.println("3. List Patient");
        System.out.print("Please choose your option :");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        switch(n){
            case 1: AddPatient();
                break;
            case 2: ServePatient();
                break;
            case 3: ListPatient();
                break;
            default : System.out.println("Sorry! Invalid Input. Returning to main menu...\n"); MainMenu();
                break;
        }


    }

    public static void AddPatient(){

        ListInterface<PatientDetails> patient = new LList<PatientDetails>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num=0;

        System.out.print("Please Enter Name :");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please Enter IC No :");
        String ic = scan.nextLine();       
        System.out.print("Please Enter Contact Number :");
        String contactNum = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Gender :");
        String gender = scan.nextLine();
        Date date = new Date();
        Long time = date.getTime();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Reason :");
        String reason = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Seriousness :");
        String seriousness = scan.nextLine();

        if(patient.isEmpty())
        {
            patient.add(new PatientDetails(name, ic, contactNum, gender,date ,time ,reason,seriousness ));
        }

        MainMenu();


    }

    public static void ServePatient(){

    }

    public static void ListPatient(){

        ListInterface<PatientDetails> patient = new LList<PatientDetails>();
        System.out.println(patient.getLength());
        if (!patient.isEmpty())
        {
            for(int i=0;i<patient.getLength();i++){
            patient.getEntry(i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error in list patients!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know what `void` means in a method signature? And do you know what a method *parameter* is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the add, list and serve are three functions. All your methods are static, then you need a static `PatientList` variable. That is, when user picked `add`, he added elements in the list, when he chose `list`, the same list objects would be displayed.

In codes just in your class declare:

```
private static ListInterface<PatientDetails> patient = new LList<PatientDetails>();
```

In your add and list method, use this variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

All your methods are marked as void. That means the have no return value. One might say, they are procedures, not functions.
If you want to return a List, you have to change the signature:

```
public static List AddPatient()
```

Then you can return your list from the method using keyword *return*.

```
return patient;
```

The parameters in brackets () are all input parameters.

This is a very basic concept of methods/functions. I suggest reading a book for begginers to understand the fundamentals of Java.

Also Java has it's own general-purpose implementation of [linked list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). You should use it, if you don't have any special requirements for it's implementation.